# Relating the cardinality to surjectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions

$f(a) = (a+p\mathbb{Z},a+q\mathbb{Z}), f:\mathbb{Z} -> \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} $ x $ \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$

I am trying to answer the following question on this map:

[image]

I have already shown $f$ is a homomorphism and found the a is in ker f if and only if a +p Z = 0+ p Z and a + q Z = 0 + q Z. This is equivalent to p|a and q|a which is again equivalnt to lcm(p,q) |a.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct, and shows that $\ker(f) = lcm(p,q)\mathbb{Z}$. Then you can apply the First Isomorphism Theorem that tells you that $\text{im}(f)\cong \mathbb{Z}/lcm(p,q)\mathbb{Z}$.

Now, the map is surjective if and only if the image and the codomain have the same cardinality, that is, if and only if $pq=lcm(p,q)$. So you can conclude the map is surjective if and only if $p,q$ are coprime.